# Calling main form from another form JavaNetbeans

Tags: java, forms, swing

Hi guys I'm new here so please bear with me..

I have two jframe forms. The main form which is Talaan and the second jframe form which is AddRecord..

The main Talaan is to populate data in Table from the database with method 
`checkDB()`.

Now my problem is when i call the second form AddRecord which is used for adding records, I want to call checkDB() method from Talaan to refresh the table to repopulate the data.. What code should I add..

I tried the codes below which does not work..

```
Talaan populate = new Talaan();
populate.checkDB();
```

Can you help me?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: It didnt work because I already tried.. Maybe I'm not very specific.. Maybe I should not insert new Talaan() because The talaan form is already present.. i ran the program talaan showed.. i clicked AddRecord and then AddRecord jframe showed.. Now, the two forms are present.. I added record to database from AddRecord.. And what i want is re initialize all components in Talaan to refresh the table..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in your checkDB(),do you use Jtable to show data from database?if you use jTable,then you can use jTable.repaint().

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I really appreciated it.. Yeah I am using jTable.. What I mean is, how do I call checkDB() method from AddRecord.. just calling checkDB method in my AddRecord class gives me an error..

Comment: (1-) You never need to use repaint() on the table. When you change the data in the TableModel the model will notify the table and the table will automatically repaint itself.

Comment: What kind of errors give u for calling checkDB() in AddRecord class?can you show your source code?

Comment: I'm sorry.. Im very new to this.. All I did was put checkDB(); in the addRecord class and obviously it gave me an error since i don't have checkDB method inside addRecord.. And the present checkDB is in Talaan.. and Talaan.checkDB doesnt work too..

Comment: please check by making checkDB()as static public method and then call this method in your AddRecord class just like Talann.checkDB().

Comment: @sawyinwaimon Don't suggest making a component `public` and `static`, it's like the worst advice you can give, neither are recommended and will cause no end of issues which we will need to fix in the future, and I'd hate to be the person to tell the OP that the advice they got was bad

Comment: oh,sorry.I forgot to consider encapsulation while considering to call method from Talann.

Comment: Hi guys.. Thanks for comments and answers especially to @sawyinwaimon.. Your suggestion is good.. It worked.. The method was called pop-upped JOptionPane but somehow other codes doesn't work especially the repopulation of the table.. But I found a way to make my programs work to my expectation.. Firstly, when I call the second frame i shoud close it using Talaan.this.dispose(), then calling the second form AddRecord.. Lastly, after adding record it will close the form call the Talaan again.. and voila, all records were refreshed.. Yay..

Answer (score 1):

> The main form which is Talaan and the second jframe form which is AddRecord..

An application should only have a single JFrame. The second window should be a modal `JDialog`.

> when i call the second form AddRecord which is used for adding records

When you click the "Add Record" button on the dialog you need to add the data from the dialog to the DefaultTableModel of the JTable.

So the easiest way to do this is to pass the DefaultTableModel as a parameter to your "AddRecord" class. then you can just use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add the data to the table.

Or, if you want to reread all the data from the database again, then your method to get the data from the database should return a `TableModel` object. Then you can just update the `JTable` using:

```
table.setModel( theUpdatedTableModel );
```

Your question is way to vague to give a specific answer.

Edit:

> how do I call checkDB() method from AddRecord..

The `checkDB` method belongs to the `Taalan` class. So you need to pass the `Taalan` class as a parameter to the `AddRecord` class.

This is basic Java. If you want to invoke a method on a class then you need to have a reference to the class.

Comment: I'm sorry for the very complicated question.. And I am ver confused too sinde I'm new to java.. And thanks for the answer.. I mean checkDB() method in the main is used for displaying the data to a table.. inside checkDB() includes tableshow.addRow(prmaryData).. so lets forget the other codes for displaying.. now in the addrecord class, i want to call checkDB there..